# Saving dynamically added LinearLayouts without using savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-layout, onresume, onpause, persistent-storage

I have a layout in which I have dynamically added custom views at a push of a button. These layouts extend LinearLayout and each carry their own unique Action objects.

The views will disappear, however, if onCreate is called again, when the user navigates away or rotates the screen. I want to keep these custom ActionHolder views there. To add to the problem, the ActionHolder objects contain sensitive information. The Action objects themselves store a live timer(that is supposed to keep on ticking even if the app is off), as well as other information.

According to an answer below, I have done the following, but to no avail. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ActionHolder extends LinearLayout implements Serializable {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2271402255369440088L;
   private Action action;
   private String timer;
   public static final int ACTION_TITLE = 0, ACTION_TIMER = 1,
         PAUSEANDPLAY_BTN = 2, FINISH_BTN = 3;



   public ActionHolder(Context context) {
      super(context);
   }



   public ActionHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
      super(context, attr);
   }



   public ActionHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attr, defStyle);
   }



   public void initiate(Action input) {
      // int hashedID = input.getActionName().hashCode();
      // if (hashedID < 0)
      // hashedID *= -1;
      // this.setId(hashedID);
      this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      action = input;
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_holder_layout, this, true);

      TextView actionTitle = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(com.tonimiko.mochi_bean.R.id.action_holder_title);
      actionTitle.setText(action.getActionName());
      actionTitle.setId(ActionHolder.ACTION_TITLE);

      TextView actionTimer = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.action_holder_timer);
      actionTimer.setId(ActionHolder.ACTION_TIMER);

      Button pauseBtn = (Button) view
            .findViewById(com.tonimiko.mochi_bean.R.id.pause_and_play_timer_btn);
      pauseBtn.setId(ActionHolder.PAUSEANDPLAY_BTN);

      Button finishBtn = (Button) view
            .findViewById(com.tonimiko.mochi_bean.R.id.finish_activity_button);
      finishBtn.setId(ActionHolder.FINISH_BTN);

      action.setActivityStartTime();
   }



   public Action finishAction() {
      action.setActivityStopTime();
      return action;
   }



   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
      super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
   }



   public String toString() {
      return "Action stored: " + action.getActionName();
   }



   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
      ActionHolder otherObj = (ActionHolder) other;
      if (this.action.getActionName().toUpperCase()
            .equals(otherObj.action.getActionName().toUpperCase()))
         return true;
      return false;
   }



   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return action.getActionName().hashCode();
   }



   @Override
   protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
      Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
      Bundle data = new Bundle();
      data.putString("Timer", timer);
      data.putSerializable("Action", action);
      Log.e("debug", "View onSaveInstanceState called!"); // TODO
      Parcelable test = new ActionHolderSavedState(superState, data);
      if(test==null)
         Log.e("debug", "NULL PARCELABLE"); // TODO
      return new ActionHolderSavedState(superState, data);
   }



   @Override
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
      Log.e("debug", "View onRestore called!");
      if (state instanceof ActionHolderSavedState) {
         final ActionHolderSavedState savedState = (ActionHolderSavedState) state;
         this.action = savedState.getAction();
         this.timer = savedState.getTimer();
         // this.initiate(action);
         super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
         Log.e("debug", "View onRestoreInstanceState finished"); // TODO
      }
   }

   static class ActionHolderSavedState extends BaseSavedState {

      private Action storedAction;
      private String storedTimer;



      public ActionHolderSavedState(Parcelable superState, Bundle data) {
         super(superState);
         storedTimer = data.getString("Timer");
         storedAction = (Action) data.getSerializable("Action");
      }



      private ActionHolderSavedState(Parcel in) {
         super(in);
         storedTimer = in.readString();
         storedAction = in.readParcelable(ActionHolder.class.getClassLoader());
      }



      public Action getAction() {
         return storedAction;
      }



      public String getTimer() {
         return storedTimer;
      }



      @Override
      public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {
         super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
         out.writeString(storedTimer);
         out.writeSerializable(storedAction);
      }

      // required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
      public static final Parcelable.Creator<ActionHolderSavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ActionHolderSavedState>() {

         public ActionHolderSavedState createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
            return new ActionHolderSavedState(in);
         }



         public ActionHolderSavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ActionHolderSavedState[size];
         }
      };
   }
}
```

Is there SOMETHING I am doing wrong? I've spend almost 4 days already on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a situation very similar to yours, with custom views being added dynamically to the screen and that need to save state when the activity is killed by the OS and recreated later, for example.

I'm overriding `onSaveInstanceState` on the custom view. It needs to return a `Parcelable` object. The key is to create a custom class that extends `BaseSavedState` and stores your data into that `Parcelable`. It would look somewhat like this:

> ```
> @Override
> protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
>     final Parcelable state = super.onSaveInstanceState();
>     return new ContainerLayoutSavedState(state, data);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onRestoreInstanceState(final Parcelable state) {
>     if (state instanceof ContainerLayoutSavedState) {
>         final ContainerLayoutSavedState savedState = (ContainerLayoutSavedState)state;
>         this.data = savedState.getData();
>         super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
>     }
> }
>
> public static class ContainerLayoutSavedState extends BaseSavedState {
>     private String data;
>
>     ContainerLayoutSavedState(final Parcelable superState, final String data) {
>         super(superState);
>         // Here in this constructor you inject whatever you want to get saved into the Parcelable object. In this contrived example, we're just saving a string called data.
>         this.data = data;
>     }
>
>
>     private ContainerLayoutSavedState(final Parcel in) {
>         super(in);
>
>         data = in.readString();
>     }
>
>     public String getData()
>         return data;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {
>         super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
>
>         out.writeString(data);
>     }
>
>     // required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
>     public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContainerLayoutSavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContainerLayoutSavedState>() {
>         @Override
>         public ContainerLayoutSavedState createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
>             return new ContainerLayoutSavedState(in);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public ContainerLayoutSavedState[] newArray(final int size) {
>             return new ContainerLayoutSavedState[size];
>         }
>     };
> } }
> ```

Also, don't forget to set IDs to your dynamically added views, so they get re-added to the View tree when you come back.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding as to what is going on here.

1. onSaveInstanceState returns a newly initialized Parcelable containing the ContainerLayoutSavedState.

2. The ContainerLayoutSavedState contains a data field...what is this data? The LinearLayout I am trying to save?

3. onRestoreInstanceState takes the received bundle and replants the data. But wait, if the data stored is an ActionHolder object (which extends LinearLayout), then how do I restore it via this.data = savedState.getData();? I have to define the getData() method myself, don't I?

Comment: The ``data`` attribute that I used was just to illustrate the kind of stuff you'd do with this code. But yeah, basically you ``ContainerLayoutSavedState`` will be the one who will persist/restore your ``LinearLayout`` from/to the ``Parcelable`` object. I will edit the code above for completeness. The concept is that the ``ContainerLayoutSavedState`` object is responsible for saving whatever instance data you wanna persist from your ``LinearLayout`` object

Comment: Now I'm getting a LinearLayout.IllegalAccessException. I also just updated my code by the way. Can you take a look at it to see if I have anything wrong?

Comment: That looks correct, except that you don't need to create a ``Bundle`` to pass into ``ContainerLayoutSavedState``, but that doens't look like a problem. Can you paste the whole stack trace?

Comment: Uh...how exactly do I copy from LogCat? There are only two lines anyhow that are being repeated:
android.widget.LinearLayout; IllegalAccessException
android.widget; IllegalAccessException

Comment: Wait, I've isolated the problem down to my saveActionsQueue() method.

Comment: oos.writeObject(currentActionsQueue); writes out the currentActionsQueue field, which is an ArrayList<ActionHolder>. Do you think this has something to do with it?

Comment: Probably... Try removing that and see if the exception goes away. You should be able to get the full stack trace from LogCat...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37293/discussion-between-tony-n-tran-and-felipe-lima)

Comment: I give up. I went around and did things the way I originally had intended: by unwrapping the data from the ActionHolders and saving them in Bundles for persistent storage. Then I loaded them and recreated the ActionLoaders. Perhaps I am doing something wrong with this code. The view's onRestoreInstanceState isn't even being called. I don't know. Hopefully someone else can use this answer, and hopefully it will work for them, as I have seen with other people's answers.