# How to add new buttons by clicking another button

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I need to add a button by click on another button (Add New). My code for button add new button

```
addnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    addnew.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == addnew)
    {
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        myButton.setId(some_random_id);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }
}
```

the above code works fine to add buttons to layout but after closing the app when i reopen it again the new button that were added earlier are not there. Can somebody help

After implementing sharedprefrences 
code for onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lvInb = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvInb);
    addnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    addnew.setOnClickListener(this);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

code for onClick

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == addnew)
    {
        count = prefs.getInt("count", 0);
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
        count++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();
    } }
```

Comment: You should read about the basics, because your question is about state of application and activity lifecycle. You shouldn't start coding without thie knowledge.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757381/saving-dynamically-added-linearlayouts-without-using-savedinstancestate

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the created buttons somewhere persistently. The code you use will not change your Layout xml which will be loaded in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`. You can use `SharedPreferences` to save the number of `Button`s you created, then add them by code after `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()`

Comment: can you tell where i need to add shared preferences

Comment: You can add it when you create a new button to save this button, or you can add it in onPause() to save the total number of buttons you have before the App goes out of View

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the number of buttons created in `sharedpreferences` and in on create, loop to that count and create these buttons.

in onCreate get sharedpref by:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Make global variable count:

```
int count=0;
```

and when you add a new button increase count:

```
addnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    addnew.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == addnew)
    {
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        myButton.setId(some_random_id);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
        count++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("count", count);
    editor.commit();
    }
}
```

In onCreate:

```
count=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
for(int i=;i<count;i++){
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        myButton.setId(some_random_id);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
}
```

You can also put add button code in another function and call that.

Don't declare sharedpref in `onCreate`,
write this in activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=null;
```

and this in onCreate:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: can you tell where i need to add shared preferences

Comment: For the "count=prefs.getBoolean("count", 0);" showin error     The method getBoolean(String, boolean) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Comment: sorry it was a typo call getInt instead

Comment: when click on addnew button in application it crashes

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: can you figure out which line it is crashing?

Comment: LogCAT Error : (1)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)      (2) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: check my edit. you are declaring shareed pref in oncreate just assign value in it.

Comment: have you written the for loop i mentioned in my ans to create previous buttons??

Comment: Error: "some_random_id" cannot be resolved to a variable